# How to use Document.PrintOut method from Microsoft.Office.Tools.Word to print the first page of a document

Tags: c#

The documentation is here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.tools.word.document.printout?view=vsto-2017

This will print the whole document:

```
Word.Application ap = new Word.Application();
Word.Document document = ap.Documents.Open(@"C:\temp\file.doc");
document.PrintOut();
```

I thought I were on to something with this as it compiled but it didn't work:

```
Word.Application ap = new Word.Application();
Word.Document document = ap.Documents.Open(@"C:\temp\file.doc");
Word.WdPrintOutRange printRange = new Word.WdPrintOutRange();
document.PrintOut(false, false, printRange,false, 1, 2);
```

`System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Type mismatch. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020005 (DISP_E_TYPEMISMATCH))'`

How do I use this method to print just the first page of the document?

Edit: This URL (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.document.printout) shows examples in VBA on how to do similar things, such as print the first 3 pages, but it's in VB and I am not sure on the c# equivalent.

Answer (score 1):

`Word.WdPrintOutRange` is an enum value. And `wdPrintFromTo` is for range selection.

```
Word.WdPrintOutRange printRange = Word.WdPrintOutRange.wdPrintFromTo;
document.PrintOut(false, false, printRange, null, 1, 2);
```

Comment: This also produced the same error `System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: 'Type mismatch. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80020005 (DISP_E_TYPEMISMATCH))'`

Comment: @user2924019 try `document.PrintOut(false, false, printRange, null, "1", "2");`

Comment: This also gave the same error. Thanks for your help regardless, something is odd about this.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get range to work.

I managed to achieve printing just the first page with this instead (Added some margins and setup the page size too):

```
Word.Application ap = new Word.Application();
Word.Document document = ap.Documents.Open(randFile);

document.PageSetup.TopMargin = 50;
document.PageSetup.RightMargin = 50;
document.PageSetup.BottomMargin = 50;
document.PageSetup.LeftMargin = 50;
document.PageSetup.PaperSize = Word.WdPaperSize.wdPaperA4;

Word.WdPrintOutRange printRange = Word.WdPrintOutRange.wdPrintCurrentPage;

document.PrintOut(false,null,printRange);
document.Close(false, false, false);
```

Comment: I love it when I accidentally come across my own answers! This has been working well for 100's of clients, but recently it has been printing random pages for a couple of people. I'm going to try get range to work again.